# How to get data from REST and run for each statement on it using AngularJS?

Tags: php, angularjs, rest

I am a newbie to angularJS, I am developing an application where my code was in PHP. I get from a REST service and then run foreach statement on it to display the data. The data i get is a PHP `object`.

How do I do the same using angularJS?

Here is my PHP code:

```
    <?php $blogs = process_api_get($base_url,'/blogs'); ?>
    <?php if($blogs != NULL) { ?>
    <?php foreach( $blogs as $blog ) : ?>

    <div class="list card">

  <a ui-sref="menu.blogsView({id: '<?php echo $blog->id; ?>', title: '<?php echo $blog->title; ?>', content: '<?php echo $blog->content; ?>' })" 
    class="item item-icon-left">
  <?php echo $blog->title; ?>
  </a>

    </div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php  } ?>

    <?php if(!$blogs) { ?>
  No blog posts found
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML would look something similar like below, where `blogs` will be blogs which are taken by server side ajax call & assigned `blogs` data in success of that `$http` call

**Markup**

```
<div class="list card" ng-repeat="blog in blogs">
    <a ui-sref="menu.blogsView({id: blog.id, title: blog.title, content:blog.content })" class="item item-icon-left">
      {{blog.title}}
    </a>
</div>
<div ng-if="blogs.length == 0">
    No blog posts found
</div>
```

**Code**

```
$http.get('/blogs').then(function(res) {
    $scope.blogs = res.data;
})
```